# I want customize Output from hasMany() in my API

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I just try to change my output json code in my Api but I can't understand how it works.

I try relationship between 2 tables. First table is `user` and second table is `LogTransfer`.

I am using Lumen (5.7.7) (Laravel Components 5.7.*)

I have two tables in relationship condition.

My first table `user` has columns `[user_id, username]` and `user_id` references column `id_source` and `id_destination` in a second table. I want to change/fill `id_source` and `id_destination` to a **username** that I got from the first table - how can I do it?

I am returning it as a json for api and it output is

```
"id_transfer": 1,
        "id_source": 3,
        "id_destination": 1,
        "jumlah": 1000,
        "waktu": "2019-01-22 04:13:00",
        "qrLog": 1,
        "jenis": "Pembelian"
```

i want my output become like this

```
"id_transfer": 1,
        "source": admin,
        "destination": iko,
        "jumlah": 1000,
        "waktu": "2019-01-22 04:13:00",
        "qrLog": 1,
        "jenis": "Pembelian"
```

Here my code is in the model Users

```
public function logTransferFrom()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LogTransfer','id_destination');
}
```

And here my code is in the controller

```
public function from(Request $request) 
{    
    $logTransfer = Auth::user()->logTransferFrom()->get();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success','result' => $logTransfer]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of functionality isn't supported out of the box since all mapping is done through the ids.But you may achieve something similar by using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) and [appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

In your Log model add this

```
public $appends = ['source', 'destination']; //dyn. appends keys to json

public function userSource()                     // mapping helper for source
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_source');
}

public function userDestination()                // mapping helper for destination
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_destination');
}

public function getSourceAttribute($value)       // gets the username for id_source
{
    return $this->userSource->username;
}

public function getDestinationAttribute($value)  // gets the username for id_destination
{
    return $this->userDestination->username;
}
```

That's it!

Now when you dump the json it should have two more keys in addition to those earlier, "source" and "destination" with values as the matching usernames from user table.

Comment: its works but badly it not just give 2 instead 4 addition keys that has reveal all data from tabel **User** that has relation with Source and Destination not just the **username** ...
the output add other additional key with a name : **user_source** & **user_destination** that reveal all column data from a table user :((

Comment: its fixed i just add protected $hidden = [ 'userDestination','userSource'] in a models thankss a lottttttt